# Application specific browsing two internet connections on same machine

Tags: linux, networking, router, bandwidth, broadband

There are 2 situations for which I am looking for a solution

- I am having 2 internet connections. One is a normal connection in our LAN (Wifi) , another    is a USB Device which has internet connectivity. I want to use both connection simultaneously on same laptop. I have some heavy files to download so I want both of these internet connections can work together so that I have increased band width.
- Any application by which I can configure which application uses which internet connection i.e. I configure Firefox to use Connection 1 and configure Internet Explorer or any other browser to use Connection 2.

Both situations are different. If there is not such app in Windows is this achievable in Linux. If yes, can you give me pointers on how to do so?

Comment: Do the two interfaces live on different networks?

Comment: yes both interfaces are on different network basically interface 1 is ISP1 and USB device is ISP 2

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you want to just "split" the traffic over your 2 connections (e.g. 1 download over connection A, another download over connection B), or actually combine their bandwidth (1 download over A and B together).

The first case (some connections over A, some over B) can be done with advanced routing, as explained in http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html. This setup "randomly" distributes the connections over both available paths.

If you want to choose yourself which connection should be started over which link, you need to dive into `iptables` to mark the connection somehow: it can be based on the program that is initiating the connection (using the `--pid-owner` match), the user that initiated the connection (using the `--uid-owner` match) or many more.

To actually combine the bandwidth, you need some cooperation on the other side of the link. One option would be to use MPTCP (http://www.multipath-tcp.org/), either to the intended end host, or to an intermediate proxy.

Comment: I am looking for answers for all the situations you pointed out.Right now the priority is to get combined bandwidth.But I am interested in knowing about all the situations you mentioned.